# The interior is in pure white color

Tags: grammaticality

> The interior is in pure white color

The 'in' is really required in this case? Is there any alternative?

Comment: [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)!

Comment: Always include context. Every word in a sentence owes its existence to its relevance to context. "in pure white color," "pure white in color," "in pure white," "pure white" are all perfectly grammatical, though each conveys a different sense. This question cannot be answered without context.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the *in* implies *painted in* (or some other colouring process) as opposed to, for example, made of something naturally white. But the difference is subtle.

The unidiomatic bit is *color*. Much more natural is *The interior is (in) pure white*. You can use ***a** pure white color*, though that is more likely if the word used to describe the colour is not itself a colour word, as in *a muddy colour*.

[Note: I use the American spelling *color* when quoting you, but *colour* elsewhere.]

Comment: Adding "color/colour" is idiomatic in Chinese (because of a plethora of homophones for the names of colors) and Japanese (at least for some colors and in some sentences), so the OP's sentence is likely a direct translation from one of those languages.